# jenkins httprequest plugin: POST request with params which contains a json string as param

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm new in jenkins pipeline scripts and traing to use the httprequest plugin, to execute a POST request which should look like this:

```
httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8', consoleLogResponseBody: true, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'POST', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'https://serverxxxx.net/v3/start?name=MyName&description={"project":"TEST", "version":"", "tags":["TAG1", "TAG2"], "associate":["ASSOC1", "ASSOC2"], "additionalProperties":{}}
```

Parameter description need to be a json string.

I'm getting the following error:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal
> character in query at index 56:
> [https://serverxxxx.net/v3/start?name=MyName&description={"project":"TEST"](https://serverxxxx.net/v3/start?name=MyName&description=%7B%22project%22:%22TEST%22),
> "version":"", "tags":["TAG1", "TAG2"], "associate":["ASSOC1",
> "ASSOC2"], "additionalProperties":{}}     at
> java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)     at
> java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3145)   at
> java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3233)    at
> java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3175)    at
> java.base/java.net.URI.(URI.java:623)   at
> java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)

How could I make this work?

Thank you.